# MVC Master Page JQuery Document Read

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using the JQuery UI accordion control that gets initialized in the $(document).ready() function.  When moving to different views, I am seeing a flicker on this menu.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I used to see this in IE6. In my case I greatly improved this by eliminating tables in the page design. Even separating header row and content row into two separate table tags almost eliminated the flickering.

Also, I think it may matter where you put the document.ready handler; I think if you put it after the accordion/body you'll see the flickering because script will only be executed after the accordion content is rendered.

Comment: `document.ready()` gets fired when the DOM is ready. It doesn't matter where you place the code in your HTML.